# Swagger: How to get formatted example json

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm really struggling to understand the format of the `examples` section of a response. I have the following response defined for a 500 Internal Sever error.

```
500InternalServerError:
    description: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    schema:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/Failure'
    headers:
      X-Rate-Limit-Limit:
        description: The number of allowed requests in the current period
        type: integer
      X-Rate-Limit-Remaining:
        description: The number of remaining requests in the current period
        type: integer
      X-Rate-Limit-Reset:
        description: The number of seconds left in the current period
        type: integer
    examples:
      application/json:
        code: -1
        message: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
```

When I load it up in swagger-ui, it looks like this:

[image: Json Response Format]

How do I get the response to be formatted over multiple lines and look like this?:

```
{
  "code": "-1",
  "message": "The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The lack of pretty print in the response-level examples seems to be a bug or missing functionality in Swagger UI 3.0.x. Feel free to submit an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues).

The workaround is to use a schema-level example instead:

```
definitions:
  Failure:
    type: object
    ...
    example:
      code: "-1"  # Quotes force the number to be treated as a string
      message: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
```

By the way, you do not need `allOf` when using `$ref` alone (without combining it with other items):

```
schema:
  $ref: '#/definitions/Failure'
```